# How to integrate sensoro sensor in iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to integrate sensoro sensor (Alpha node 4AA) in my application.I tried my best to integrate it in my application but I can't do that. I can't find the solution.

I used given the description in  http://docs.sensoro.com/en/sdk/ios_sdk.html and the demo given in this site is showing so many errors like "Sensorodevicedelegate not available".